RabbiMQ connection breakage issue in ASP.NET Core
Creating a system for getting messages from the RabbitMQ server and continuously consuming messages from the queue using the Background service.
So I first constructed a BackgroundTaskService class that implements the BackgroundService interface and registered it in Startup.cs. In BackgroundTaskService.cs, use the ExecuteAsync function to invoke a Receiver.cs method to consume messages if there are any in the queue.
ReceiveMessages is a method in Receiver.cs that is invoked from the ExecuteAsync method. The ReceiveMessages method accepts a cancellingToken, which is used to send a return after completing a job. This allows ExecuteAsync to look for another time. In the ReceiveMessages method, create a Consumer and use the basicConsume function to consume messages. Use ManualResetEvent to wait until the set() signal is received before consuming.The received method will be completed, and the cancellingToken will be returned.However, the Consumer Received callback method does not wait for ManualResetEvent to waitOne().
I'm also concerned about the stability of the RabbitMQ connection. Although the code establishes the connection in a using block, but a connection still closing during operation.
We tried the following code, and when the background service called the ReceiveMessages method for the second time, we got an error like this.

System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.AutorecoveringModel'.'

Here is an example code for the Receiver class.
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections;
using RabbitMQ.Client;
using RabbitMQ.Client.Events;
using RMQ.Services;
using System.Data;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace RMQ
{
    public class Receiver : RMQServices
    {
        private readonly string _queueName;
        private readonly ConnectionFactory _connectionFactory;
        private readonly RMQServices _RMQServices;
        ManualResetEvent resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        public Receiver()
        {
            _queueName = "testQueue";
            _connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
        }
        public async Task<CancellationToken> ReceiveMessages(CancellationToken cancellingToken)
        {
            int count = await GetMessageCountAsync("http://localhost:15672", "/", _queueName, "guest", "guest");
            int ReceivedMsg = 0;
            if (count > 0)
            {
                using (var connection = _connectionFactory.CreateConnection())
                using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
                {
                    var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
                    consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
                    {
                        var body = ea.Body.ToArray();
                        var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                        channel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false);
                        ReceivedMsg += 1;
                        if (count == ReceivedMsg)
                        {
                            resetEvent.Set();
                        }
                    };
                    channel.BasicConsume(queue: _queueName, autoAck: false, consumer: consumer);
                    resetEvent.WaitOne();
                }
            }
            return cancellingToken;
        }
        public async Task<int> GetMessageCountAsync(string rabbitMQBaseUrl, string vhost, string queueName, string username, string password)
        {
            string url = $"{rabbitMQBaseUrl}/api/queues/{Uri.EscapeDataString(vhost)}/{Uri.EscapeDataString(queueName)}";
            var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
            {
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password)
            };
            var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var jsonDoc = JsonDocument.Parse(responseBody);
                int messageCount = 0; // Assuming 'messages' contains the count of messages in the queue
                if (jsonDoc.RootElement.TryGetProperty("messages", out JsonElement property))
                {
                    messageCount = (int)ConvertJsonElementToInt(property);
                }
                return messageCount;
            }
            else
            {
                // Handle error
                Console.WriteLine($"Failed to retrieve message count. Status code: {response.StatusCode}");
                return 0;
            }
        }
        private int? ConvertJsonElementToInt(JsonElement element)
        {
            // Check if the JsonElement represents a number
            if (element.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Number)
            {
                if (element.TryGetInt32(out int intValue))
                {
                    return intValue; // Return the integer value
                }
            }
            return null; // If conversion failed
        }
    }
}


Here is an example code for the BackgroundTaskService class.
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using RMQ;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace RMQ
{
    public class BackgroundTaskService : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<BackgroundTaskService> _logger;
        private readonly Receiver _receiver;
        private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;

        public BackgroundTaskService(ILogger<BackgroundTaskService> logger, Receiver rec)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _receiver = rec;
            _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        }
        protected async override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellingToken)
        {
            while (!cancellingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Background service is running...");
                await _receiver.ReceiveMessages(cancellingToken);
            }
        }
    }
}


